# Sublime Text 2 Context Menu in Windows 8

Tags: registry, editor, contextmenu

As you may know, Windows 8 came out yesterday. I have upgraded, and everything seems to be working fine, but when I installed Sublime Text 2 for my code editor, the button in the context menu that used to say "Edit with Sublime Text 2" is not there anymore. I have tried using a custom registry script, and it adds the button, but Windows 8 *still* asks me what program I want to open it with. Here's the script I used:

(Saved as add_context_menu.reg)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2]

@="Open with S&ublime Text 2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2\command]

@="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe \"%1\""
```

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

I am using `Sublime Text 2` in `Windows 8` and I have no problem with the `Open with Sublime Text 2` button, actually I opened the .reg using it :)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Sublime Text 2\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe \"%1\""
```

I guess the fact you weren't escaping your backslashes might be the problem

Comment: Note that when you install Sublime Text and allow the installer to add the context menu, it creates registry entries without escaped backslashes.  Maybe this is a bug in the installer?

Answer (score 2):

Here you find two very detailed and well commented .reg files for Windows Context Menus. One for Version 2 and another one for Version 3 of Sublime Text.

https://github.com/cbmeeks/sublime-text-2-context-menu-windows

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 8 the below code worked for me

`C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe "%1"`

Answer (score 1):

This is a better command. just save it to a bat file in app directory and run as administrator.

U can use this command for another applications like Atom,VSCode,... simply by changing App* lines

```
@echo off
SET AppKey=SublimeText3
SET AppTitle=Open with Sublime Text 3
SET AppPath=%~dp0sublime_text.exe
SET AppIcon=%AppPath%,0

REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%AppKey%" /ve /f /d "%AppTitle%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%AppKey%" /v "Icon" /f /d "%AppIcon%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\%AppKey%\command" /ve /f /d "%AppPath% \"%%1\""

REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\%AppKey%" /ve /f /d "%AppTitle%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\%AppKey%" /v "Icon" /f /d "%AppIcon%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\%AppKey%\command" /ve /f /d "%AppPath% \"%%v\""

REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\%AppKey%" /ve /f /d "%AppTitle%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\%AppKey%" /v "Icon" /f /d "%AppIcon%"
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\%AppKey%\command" /ve /f /d "%AppPath% \"%%v\""
```